# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '...internalEventListenerProcessor'

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am integrating spring into my hibernate project. I am getting the error which i am not able to understand.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>yogi.demo.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

spring.xml(Spring config file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.prop" />
    <!-- context:component-scan base-package="base.package"/ -->

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packageToScan" value="yogi.demo.hibernate.demo"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Place holder file:- config.prop

```
# jdbc.X
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
jdbc.user=sa
jdbc.pass=
# hibernate.X
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Utils.java

```
@Component
public class Utils {

    @Autowired
    private  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

DAO class:
App.java

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        Session session =  context.getBean("utils",Utils.class).getSessionFactory().openSession();//new Utils().getSessionFactory().openSession(); // Utils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }
}
```

When I am running this application I got below error from PostProcessor whcih I am not able to fix.

```
Apr 10, 2017 3:32:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@b07fd3: startup date [Mon Apr 10 15:32:38 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 10, 2017 3:32:38 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
Apr 10, 2017 3:32:38 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata: method <init>()V not found
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at yogi.demo.hibernate.demo.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:351)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:992)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    ... 11 more
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Comment: Looks like mixture of spring versions

Comment: You are mixing Spring 2.5.1 and 4.3.7 jars, that is trouble waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3):

@StanislavL your correct, I am getting this error because of mixed spring jar version.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            **<version>2.5.1</version>** <== changes to 4.3.7.RELEASE and it worked for me
        </dependency>
```